# Get the installed version of SharePoint Add-In CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app, version

I have a SharePoint hosted app (*or, add-in*). The app can be added to a SharePoint page via a ClientWebPart. I want to read the current installed version of the app, from within the app, when it is loaded. SharePoint displays the version in the SiteContents however, I don't know of any api which can return the same value to my code. Plz advice.

Since, it's a SharePoint hosted app, I can only use JavaScript csom.